# User permission to list databases

Tags: postgresql, upgrade

I have exported all databases using `pg_dumpall`, then I imported them using `psql`. for the database "command" the are 2 users, "jo" is the owner and "ko" can manipulate all tables(list, edit, delete).

when I connect to the database using the user "jo" `psql -U jo -h localhost -d command` I can list all tables.
I run the command `\z login` I get

```
                              Access privileges
 Schema | Name  | Type  | Access privileges  | Column privileges | Policies 
--------+-------+-------+--------------------+-------------------+----------
 command| login | table | jo=arwdDxt/jo   +|                   | 
        |       |       | ko=arwdDxt/jo   +|                   |
```

but when I connect using "ko" `psql -U ko -h localhost -d command`, I run the `\dt` I get

```
Did not find any relations.
```

when I run `select * from command.login;` I get the data inside the login table, when run `select * from login` I get the error

```
ERROR:  relation "login" does not exist
LINE 1: select * from login;
```

How can I list the tables using the user "ko" ?

Answer (score 1):

Simple: put schema `command` on the `search_path` and give user `ko` `USAGE` permissions on the schema.

Comment: I've update my poste:

when I run select * from jo.login; I get the data inside the table login , when run select * from login I get the error

ERROR:  relation "login" does not exist
LINE 1: select * from login;

Comment: Your question said that the schema name was `command`. At any rate, that shows that it is the first alternative in my answer: the schema was not on the `search_path`.

Comment: I run this command ALTER ROLE ko SET search_path TO command;
but still the same problem

Comment: I tried GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA command TO ko;   now even the owner "jo" cannot list the table 
\dt
Did not find any relations.

Comment: when I type select * from command.login; I can see the content of the table

Comment: You said the schema was `jo`, not `command`. You have to sort this out yourself; what you say is confusing.

Comment: I fix the problem when I run SET search_path TO command;

Comment: the schema is "command"